# Git join two different threads

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Our repo was ported from SVN. Because of some non-standard operation on SVN, `git-svn` generated different threads like the following

```
 C0 <- C1 <- C2 ...
       C1' <- C2' ...
```

Where C0 and C1' are all "initial commits", which means all changes are "adding files".

Now what I am going to do is, join C1' to C0 to ensure they share the same root

```
C0 <- C1 <- C2 ...
    |<- C1'' <- C2' ...
C1'
```

Here C1'' is a commit that is a merge of C0 and C1', but the final state is equivalent to C1'. So then the later chain nodes can remain unchanged.

Are there any combination of `git` commands can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See help page for git replace and try the following command

git replace --graft C1' C0

For Git versions older than 2.1 use

```
NEW_SHA=$(echo "Replacement commit" | git commit-tree -p CO C1'^{tree} -F -)
git replace C1' $NEW_SHA
```

Comment: It uses an obscure feature of git that allows you to replace one object with a different one.  In this instance you would create a new object with the same tree but different parents, and then replace your old commit with that.  The help page for replace explains in more detail.

Comment: This command seems only available in the latest version (2.1.0) and it is not available in 1.9.4, which means I can only use this version by building it from source code. (The current official `git` GUI for Windows ships with 1.9.4) Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Manually create the commit first with **echo "Replacement commit" | git commit-tree -p CO C1'^{tree} -F - **, this will print out NEW_SHA.  Then do **git replace C1' NEW_SHA**.  This should work with older versions of git.

Comment: Greate, I will test this and if this works, can you please put those additional knowledge in comments to the actual answer so I can accept this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The literal answer is no: the problem is that a commit is a checksum of all of its contents, *including* its parent ID(s), so if you have a `C2'` that points to a `C1'` and you make a new copy `C1''`, you must make a new copy `C2''` to point to `C1''`, and so on.

That said, the obvious command to do the job is `git filter-branch`: you can use a commit filter to copy `C1'` to a new commit that has `C0` as a parent, and then let that change ripple through the entire remainder of the commit-graph.  However, if you're going to do that, it might make more sense to redo the import.  (I'm no expert at SVN imports.  I've done a few CVS-to-git imports before and I did a few test imports and then redid them with better options, etc.  It was very slow, but that was all just computer time, while I did other things.)

Comment: Yes, I have did a lot of attempts of svn import, and the above is which I believed the best I can get...